# Get Sample SOAP request programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, asmx

I'm writing a tool to help users make use of my ASMX webservice, and I'd like to show the users sample SOAP requests for various methods.

If you have an asmx webservice ASP.NET automatically generates a page for each method which displays a sample SOAP request and response. You can see an example [here](http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?op=GetCityWeatherByZIP).

Clearly, a `System.Web.Services.WebService` generates this sample somewhere, but I don't know where. How can I get hold of the soap samples programmatically so that I can use them elsewhere?

Comment: SoapUI is a great tool for that, you don't need to write your own :) But you can always read everything from wsdl, SoapUI also uses wsdl file to generate requests/examples http://wsf.cdyne.com/weatherws/weather.asmx?wsdl

Comment: @IMU - I know I don't need to write my own, and I know I can consume the WSDL, but that's not what I want - I want to automatically show SOAP and manipulate examples elsewhere on my site.